# How to copy files which are present in multiple directories within multiple sub folders two levels up?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cassandra, datastax

I am copying snapshot files from 30 keyspace folders which contain multiple sub folders to a folder two levels up.
I want to do this thing for all nested folders :

**from directory**:

```
/data/disk01/keyspace1/table1/snapshots/1475505658586/*
```

**to directory**:

```
/data/disk01/keyspace1/table1/
```

my command will traverse in all "keyspace" named folders and also go into each sub folders of it and then copy the files two levels up .

FYI, we have 30 folders of keyspace (example- keyspace1,keyspace2..and so on , tables like table1,table2,table3 ,...and so on , disk1,disk2,disk3 , disk4 & disk5).

How can I copy the files from folder "/1475505658586" to two levels up at /table ?
One command should perform all the copy job.

Comment: I wonder, why only one command? What about a simple loop?

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
cd /data/disk01/keyspace1/table1/snapshots/1475505658586
cp -ar keyspace* ../..
```